# Bash script - How to put double quote around string value in variable?

Tags: bash, double-quotes, mosquitto

In bash script, I have a variable, say $date, that obtained string value from some other function, say the value of $date is 04 Feb 2020. I want to mosquitto_pub the value in $date, but it can't because mosquitto_pub expect no space after 04. I understand that I have to put the double quote around 04 Feb 2020 (as if $date='"04 Feb 2020"'), how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You don't include quotes in the variable. You just quote the parameter expansion. `date="04 Feb 2020"; some_command "$date"`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is quote the parameter expansion. Given

```
date="04 Feb 2020"
```

a command line like

```
some_command $date
```

will pass 3 arguments (`04`, `Feb`, and `2020`) to `some_command` after the shell applies word-splitting to the result of the parameter expansion.

To prevent the word-splitting, you simply need to quote the parameter expansion, not add literal quotes to the result.

```
some_command "$date"
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quote:

```
d="04 Feb 2010"; d2="\"$d\""; echo $d2
"04 Feb 2010"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The double quote is there by your example; but mosquitto_pub still report "Error: Unknown option 'Feb'." Do you know what might cause this error?

Comment: My bash script command that generated such error: ...

mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t purpleair/lastseenddmmyy -m $lastseenddmmyy ....

the $lastseenddmmyy contain "04 Feb 2020". The double quotes are there when I echoed the variable.....

When I run it on terminal, it has no problem....
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t purpleair/lastseenddmmyy -m "04 Feb 2020"  ....